# How to get the last parent page slug or id in wordpress theme development?

Tags: php, wordpress

Given a sceanrio, for example:

- Page 1
- Page 2

  - Page 3

    - Page 4

      - Page 5
      - Page 6

        - Page 7
  - Page 8

How to get the last parent page slug or id in wordpress theme development, using only the ID of the top most parent page?

The top most parent page in the scenario given is "Page 2"
Following the sceanario given the last parent page in the hierarchy is "Page 6".

Comment: Well, that depends. Where exactly in your theme do you need to do this?

Comment: I need it in a wordpress page which am customizing via code

Comment: In that case, to get the parent ID of the current post/page this should do: `global $post; $parent_page_id = $post->parent_id;` (place this inside the loop).

Comment: Sorry, but i already have the page ID of the top most parent page, given in the above case, it is Page 2.
However using the ID of Page 2, I would somewhow like to get the ID of "Page 6".

Note:
 
"Page 6" has the top most parent page which is "Page 2".
"Page 6" is also one of the child of "Page 2".
"Page 6" is the last page which should also be a parent of another page, in our case the child of "Page 6" is "Page 7".

Am trying to target the last page in the hierarchy, which must be a parent also.

Comment: I’d say, what you want is basically a search for the lowest, right-most non-leaf in a sorted tree structure (assuming the children are sorted by ascending by ID from left to right on each level.) So go look up which WP functions help to generate the structure you have outlined above as an array, and then research what algorithm could be used to implement said search.